# JCO PoolManager: How to confirm if JCO Pool is created in JCO PoolManager by looking at JCO traces

Tags: jco

I am trying to analyze one problem where in JCO Trace file I can see that the JCO Pool is added as follows

```
SAPEngine_Application_Thread[impl:3]_12 [14:44:41:772]: [JAV-LAYER] JCO.PoolManager.addPool: 
     name = pool name, 
     connection = connection, 
     pool_size = 20, 
     max_wait_time = 30000, 
     pooled_connection_timeout = 600000, 
     timeout_check_period = 60000
```

but after this when I try to get a connection from this pool I get following error

```
SAPEngine_Application_Thread[impl:3]_12 [14:45:00:942]: [JAV-LAYER] JCO.PoolManager.getClient(poolName, true) Error: application tries to get client from removed or non existent pool.
```

This error occurs just after my XI system is restarted, rest of the time it works as expected. XI system has two stacks JAVA AS and ABAP AS.

I tried to go through the JRFC logs and `defaultTrace.log` files but no clues are yet found on this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I Don't know very much about XI, but from your trace it looks like the added pool is actually named "pool name" while from the error message it seems that your application/XI tries to get a connection from a pool named "poolName". Maybe you should check your configuration..?

Comment: Hi Carsten, thanks for your help, I checked the names and they are exactly same, I just replaced those with a dummy names while posting this thread